# Onsen UI 2.0 How to change Material color?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

How to change the color of objects like , its always 'teal'. IOS color/design is good but for android I want to have a different color.

Note: Onsen UI 2.0

Comment: https://onsen.io/v2/docs/guide/js/#css-definitions

Comment: No problem, I really recommend their theme roller (I think they call it a component roller now).  A trick I learned was to actually click on the component after you change the items you want, then it gives you just the CSS you need and not the whole theme.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

- Use the theme roller and download the custom CSS: http://components.onsen.io/
- Use the source `stylus` files from the `onsen-ui` npm package, edit the colour variables in one of the theme files and compile it using a stylus compiler, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus

You can also add custom CSS definitions that override the colours of components, but in that way you cannot change the primary colour throughout the whole application.

Comment: Starting from version 2.2.0, the theme roller is not an option anymore. "The old Theme Roller will not be updated anymore but it will keep working for previous versions (up to 2.1.0)." See announcement: https://onsen.io/blog/220-release

Comment: So how to customize theme now?